# How to get and set value in nested form fields in angular2?

Tags: angular

I am working on angular2 application and using angular reactive forms.
How to get value of innermost element and set its value.

```
form : FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder)
{
   this.form = formBuilder.group({
      'home_cleaning' : [{
           cities : FormBuilder.array([])
       }]
   });
}

setValue()
{
    let cities_array = [1,2,3,4];
    this.form.controls['home_cleaning']['cities'].setValue(cities_array);
}

getValue()
{
   console.log(this.form.controls['home_cleaning']['cities'].value);
}
```

Getting error in console : Cannot read property 'setValue/value'  of undefined.

Comment: May be you have a typo in `setVlaue` --> `setValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    form : FormGroup;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder)
    {
       this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          'home_cleaning' : this.formBuilder.array([
             this.formBuilder.group({
                cities : this.formBuilder.array([])
             })
          ])
       });
    }

   setValue()
   {
      let cities_array = [1,2,3,4];
      (this.form.controls['home_cleaning'].value).forEach((value, key)=> {
         let citiesArray = <FormArray>(<FormArray>this.form.controls['home_cleaning']).controls[key].get('cities');
         for(let city of cities_array){
            citiesArray.push(new FormControl(city))
         }
      });
      this.getValue();
   }

   getValue()
   {
      (this.form.controls['home_cleaning'].value).forEach((value, key)=> {
         let citiesArray = <FormArray>(<FormArray>this.form.controls['home_cleaning']).controls[key].get('cities').value;
      });
   }
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this answer

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = formBuilder.group({
      'home_cleaning': formBuilder.group({
        cities: [] //if you want to set values as normal array if you want to create FormArray use new FormArray([]) and push formCotrols in this array.
      })
    });
}

setValue() {
    let cities_array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    this.form.get(['home_cleaning','cities']).setValue(cities_array);
}

getValue() {
    console.log(this.form.get(['home_cleaning','cities']).value);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to populate your form with data, you have to patch it

```
this.form.patchValue(dataObject);
```

or

```
this.form.patchValue({
   'home_cleaning': { cities: 'value' }
});
```

With [patchValue](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patchvalue), you can assign values to specific controls in a FormGroup by supplying an object of key/value pairs for just the controls of interest.

you can merge the object

```
this.form.patchValue(Object.assign(this.form.value, youNewDataObject)));
```

or

```
this.form.patchValue(dataObj, {selfOnly: true });
```

Comment: I have implemented this but getting one problem that if I have more then one field in home_cleaning field then patch value will over write all fields.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, solved it like this :

```
this.newEmployeeForm = new FormGroup({

controls..............

and nested Form:
      PersonalAdress : new FormGroup({
            StreetName: new FormControl(null),
            StreetNumber: new FormControl(null),
            ZipCode : new FormControl(null),
            Region: new FormControl(null)

 })
})
```

So I just use a Path like I would use inside my HTML code:

```
 this.newEmployeeForm.get('PersonalAdress.StreetName').setValue(data);
```

Like this you can set even the deepest nesting form elements, as long as you provide the right path.

*Note that I give the get method a string.*

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
   setValue() {
    let cities_array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        home_cleaning: this.formBuilder.array([
            [({
                cities: cities_array,

            })],
        ]),
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By comments it seems that you want to just push new values to your form Array, then let's just use `map` for that, and push new form controls:

```ts
setValue() {
  let cities_array = [1,2,3,4];
  let arr = this.form.get('home_cleaning.cities').controls;
  cities_array.map(city => arr.push(new FormControl(city)))
}
```

PS. Here I assume you have typo, and that `home_cleaning` is actually an nested form group.

And for getting the value, just do:

```ts
this.form.get('home_cleaning.cities').value
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar and found this pattern worked well in the template:

```
<span class="label-error" *ngIf="(form.controls['parentControl'].controls['childControl'].invalid && attemptedSubmit)">Please select childControl.</span>
```